# Preventing a multitude of style-related React props using CSS Modules

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

In my project, I have a `Text` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { bool, string, number, element, func, object, any } from 'prop-types'
import cx from 'classnames'
import s from './styles/Text.css'


const Text = (props) => {
  const renderMultiLines = () => {
    const items = props.children.split(' ')
    return items.map(text => <div style={{ marginBottom: '2px' }} className={s.multiLineItem}>{text}</div>)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={cx(
        s.text,
        props.ellipsis && s.ellipsis,
        props.isUpperCase && s.isUpperCase,
        props.isBold && s.bold,
        props.isExtraBold && s.extraBold,
        props.isExtraSpaced && s.extraSpaced,
        props.multiLine && s.multiLine,
        props.active && s.underlined,
        props.active && s.primary,
        s[props.color],
        s[props.size],
      )}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      style={props.style}
    >
      {!props.multiLine && props.children}
      {props.multiLine && renderMultiLines()}
    </div>
  )
}

Text.defaultProps = {
  isBold: false,
  isExtraSpaced: false,
  isExtraBold: false,
  children: '',
  color: '',
  ellipsis: false,
  size: 'extraExtraSmall',
  isUpperCase: false,
  onClick: undefined,
  style: {},
  active: false,
}

Text.propTypes = {
  isBold: bool,
  isExtraSpaced: bool,
  isExtraBold: bool,
  children: any,
  color: string,
  ellipsis: bool,
  size: string,
  isUpperCase: bool,
  onClick: func,
  style: object,
  active: bool,
}

export default Text
```

As you can see, the intention is that you pass in props to change the layout of the text.

The idea is that you only ever end up with a limited amount of styles for text, and you never end up with slight variations.

An example of the usage of this component in my project looks like this:

```
<Text
  onClick={() => this.handleGlobalChangeDate(Number(n))}
  isBold
  size="medium"
  color="primary"
  active={Number(n) === activeDay && visibleMonth === activeMonth}
>{n}</Text>
```

This looks messy, and I feel like `isBold`, `size`, `color` etc should not need to be displayed here and passed in as props. Rather, they should be handled in the CSS and refer to the project's `variables.css` file.

In this way I would like to be able to attach a `className` to the `Text` component in question.

However, because it's a component and not simply a `div`, for example, the `className` would merely get passed to the component as a prop.

How can I use CSS to deal with this issue instead of using a multitude of style-related props?

Answer (score 0):

Try [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), a great way to add classes dynamically based upon props or state.

With this you can do:

```
var btnClass = classNames({
  btn: true,
  'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
  'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
});
return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
```

Then apply in your component:

```
<div className={btnClass}>Something</div>
```